# Python ShellWindows Internet Explorer get Page Source

Tags: python, windows, internet-explorer, hook

I'm trying to get some data from all running IE instances to hook the logged username from the page source, i tried with selenium to make the users run IE from selenium and then when the user logs in i get the Username and it kinda works in the first tab only, if the user go to the login page from another window/tab, i can't catch that. It looks like selenium with IE window_handles dont work very well. 
Searching on google i might have found something better for me that could grab some data from stock internet explorer in all running tabs/windows. 
Following [this link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/269345-how-to-connect-to-an-already-running-instance-of-i/) i was able to get the Page Title and the Location URL and it also explain how to make the page navigate to another URL.
Now what I cant find is how to get the page source.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch 
from win32gui import GetClassName

ShellWindowsCLSID = '{9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39}'
ShellWindows = Dispatch ( ShellWindowsCLSID )

for sw in ShellWindows :
    if GetClassName ( sw . HWND ) == 'IEFrame' :
        print(sw)
        print(sw.LocationName)
        print(sw.LocationURL)
        #sw.Document.Location = "http://python.org" navigating to another url
        print(50 * '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from [this link](http://www.mayukhbose.com/python/IEC/) so basically to get the page Source

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch 
from win32gui import GetClassName

ShellWindowsCLSID = '{9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39}'
ShellWindows = Dispatch ( ShellWindowsCLSID )

for sw in ShellWindows :
    if GetClassName ( sw . HWND ) == 'IEFrame' :
        #print the source
        print(sw.Document.body.outerHTML)

        #get all elements
        elements = sw.Document.all

        #get all inputs
        inputs = [x for x in elements if x.tagName == "INPUT"] # tag name is always uppercase

        #get all buttons
        buttons = [x for x in elements if x.tagName == "BUTTON"]

        #get by class name
        rows = [x for x in elements if "row" in x.className.split(' ')]

        #get by id
        username = [x for x in elements if x.getAttribute("id") == "username"]
```

Analyzing the file IEC.py you can see that you can set input value or click button, etc.